# Cannot rotate my player while my camera does

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So while I was creating my look script for the game, I followed a YouTube tutorial where he had create a empty object named **orientationpos** inside player which stores the orientation of the player, and a camera holder outside player which uses the orientationpos gameobject as a reference to the script.

Here's my player camera script

```
using Photon.Pun;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
public float sensX;
public float sensY;

public Transform Orientation;

public float xRotation;
public float yRotation;

PhotonView pv;

public void Awake()
{
    pv = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
}
public void Start()
{
    Orientation = GameObject.FindWithTag("OrientLink").transform;


    // if not local player it disables the camera for muliplayer as unity only renders 1 camera at time
}
private void Update()
{
    if (Orientation == null)
    {
        Orientation = GameObject.FindWithTag("OrientLink").transform;
    }
    else
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

        yRotation += mouseX;
        xRotation -= mouseY;

        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
        Orientation.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
    }
}

public void Linkpc()
{
    Orientation = GameObject.FindWithTag("OrientLink").transform;
}
}
```

I think I know the problem That is the rotation is being applied to the orientationpos which is inside a player gameobject, i.e. orientationpos is child of the player gameobject due to which the rotation of orientationpos is not applied to player gameobject.

Is there any way to apply rotation of child gameobject to parent gameobject.

please let me know if I am correct.

Comment: `Orientation.parent.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);` ?